# Send mail using GraphClient always goes to junk folder

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I'm trying to send an email using Microsoft Graph API using following code spinet. It always end up in recipient's SPAM/JUNK folder.

```
try {
    val usernamePasswordCredential: UsernamePasswordCredential = UsernamePasswordCredentialBuilder()
            .clientId(clientId).username(username).password(password).build()

    val tokenCredentialAuthProvider = TokenCredentialAuthProvider(usernamePasswordCredential)
    val graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider(tokenCredentialAuthProvider).buildClient()

    val bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("messages")
    val pattern = bundle.getString("email.body")

    val message = Message()
    message.subject = bundle.getString("email.subject")

    val body = ItemBody()
    body.contentType = BodyType.HTML

    val content = MessageFormat.format(pattern, voornamen, demoLink, USERNAME, pwd)
    body.content = content
    message.body = body

    val toEmail = EmailAddress()
    toEmail.address = email
    val recipient = Recipient()
    recipient.emailAddress = toEmail
    message.toRecipients = listOf(recipient)

    graphClient.me().sendMail(
            UserSendMailParameterSet
                    .newBuilder()
                    .withMessage(message)
                    .build()
    ).buildRequest().post()
} catch (e: Exception) {
    logger.error(e) {"Exception in sending email"}
    throw TenantCreationException("Email", "Failed with error message : ${e.localizedMessage}")
}
```

When I'm trying to send same email content with same account using outlook.office365.com. It goes into inbox only.
Can anyone please suggest what am I missing here?

Comment: This is not really a programming question as your code does send the email. That said, it can depend on many things: the content and headers of your emails, receiving server's policies, and the reputation of the sender IP address or domain (which explains why you'd get different treatment). Check your emails with spamassassin or such. Get on the recipient server's postmaster mailing lists and read their postmaster hints. If nothing helps, get professional help, look for email deliverability consulting.

Comment: Yes @Robert, Initially I've also the same doubt that the issue can not be resolved by any code change. Due to the same reason we've already asked for microsoft support to check the issue (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1039530/email-goes-into-spam.html). And they have suggested to check DKIM configuration. Which we are also checking in parallel.
Apart from this I don't think its the issue of the content and the sender's IP as I'm able to send same content using outlook from the same device.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? I am using azure ms graph api to send emails and they go to spam as you said however our domain is already verified in azure portal so we can use outlook from that same email account and send from outlook interface and it will go to the inbox. Makes no sense as I thought ms graph api email sending used same protocols and would by default use headers which include a signed dkim.